# Background image is too small on mobile devices. How to fix?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is set to a width of 100%, with a background image (pictured below, the background image is the hand holding the appliance), so resizing the window will resize the background image as well. I did this with the intent of having it always stretch across the entire screen, regardless of what device you were using.

[image]

This works fine until I launch the website on a mobile phone. The phone screen is too small horizontally and shrinks the background-image to a point that the 3 infobox divs at the bottom of the screen appear to be pushed off, but its just the background-image that has been pulled up:

[image]

Does anyone know how I could work around this problem? Should I find a way to position the infobox divs in a way that causes them to move upwards when the screen is smaller?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You are asking us to make design decisions for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to hold it's aspect ratio, you can set the height to 100% and let it ruin the aspect ratio or just fade out the bottom of the image so it appears to blend in.

Comment: I definitely don't want to ruin the ratio of the image.

Comment: The size of your element has nothing to to with the size of your background image.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a different background image for different platforms, for backward compatibility, otherwise use CSS3's `background-size`. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp for details.

Comment: I currently am using `background-size`. I have its width set to 100% and the height on auto. This is what shrinks it on mobile devices, because the width is relatively small. Should I find a way to detect when it is opened on a mobile device and change the size?

Comment: You probably already know your parent container for your background image's size. You should have your parent elements size set. Look at your CSS `@media` or `@import` for your mobile CSS.